# ASP.Net Core 3.1 Stripe Payment AND RAZOR Pages add db record

Tags: asp.net, stripe-payments

> I have a simple ASP.NET Core RAZOR page app (NOT MVC) which adds
>   records to a database, works great. I also have a simple ASP.NET Core
>   MVC app which adds a single payment with Stripe Checkout, works great.
>   I need to combine the two, preferably to have a simple RAZOR Page
>   which writes to DB and then calls the Stripe Checkout straight after
>   writing the record. It does not matter if it works the other way
>   around whereby by the Stripe payment is made and then the write to DB
>   takes place. Preferably I would like to get on a single submit button
>   but if it needs two one for create record and one for submit payment,
>   no problem. How can I get a button to run both routines ie add db
>   record and call Stripe payment routine. Any pointers would be very
>   much appreciated.
>
> **ASP.NET Core RAZOR Pages**
>
> Create.cshtml:
>
> ```
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <label asp-for="Amtratable.id" class="control-label"></label>
>             <input asp-for="Amtratable.id" class="form-control" />
>             <span asp-validation-for="Amtratable.id" class="text-danger"></span>
>         </div>
>
>         <div class="form-group">
>             <label asp-for="Amtratable.surname" class="control-label"></label>
>             <input asp-for="Amtratable.surname" class="form-control" />
>             <span asp-validation-for="Amtratable.surname" class="text-danger"></span>
>         </div> .....
>
>        <div class="form-group">
>             <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
>         </div>
>     </form>    
>
> Create.cshtml.cs:
>
> public class CreateModel : PageModel
> {
>     private readonly StripeRazorTest.Data.StripeRazorTestContext _context;
>
>     public CreateModel(StripeRazorTest.Data.StripeRazorTestContext context)
>     {
>         _context = context;
>     }
>
>     public IActionResult OnGet()
>     {
>         return Page();
>     }
>
>     [BindProperty]
>     public AmtraTestCl AmtraTestCl { get; set; }
>     public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
>     {
>         //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Create))
>         {
>             if (!ModelState.IsValid)
>             {
>                 return Page();
>             }
>
>             _context.AmtraTestCl.Add(AmtraTestCl);
>             await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
>
>             return RedirectToPage("./Index");
>        }
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> **ASP.NET Core MVC**
>
> Index.cshtml:
>
> @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) {
>       
>           Name
>           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
>           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
>       
>       
>           Email Address
>           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
>           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
>       
>       
>           Friday Night Adults
>           @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FridayAdults)
>           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FridayAdults)
>
> ```
> <div>
>     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
> </div> }
>
>  HomeController.cs:
> ```
>
> public class HomeController : Controller
>       {
>           public IActionResult Index()
>           {
>               RegistrationModel model = new RegistrationModel();
>               return View(model);
>           }
>
> ```
>     [HttpPost]
>     public IActionResult Index(RegistrationModel model)
>     {
>         if (ModelState.IsValid)
>         {
>             List<SessionLineItemOptions> items = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>();
>
>             {
>                 items.Add(new SessionLineItemOptions
>                 {
>                     Name = "Surname",
>                     Description = "The name",
>                     Amount = 700,
>                     Currency = "gbp",
>                     Quantity = 1
>                 });
>             }
>
>             var options = new SessionCreateOptions
>             {
>
>                 PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
>                 {
>                     "card"
>                 },
>                 LineItems = items,
>                 SuccessUrl = "https://localhost:44329/",
>
>                 //SuccessUrl = "https://localhost:44318/",
>                 CancelUrl = "http://localhost:5000/"
>             };
>
>             SessionService service = new SessionService();
>             Session session = service.Create(options);
>
>             PaymentModel paymodel = new PaymentModel
>             {
>                 ChargeID = session.Id
>             };
>            return View("Payment", paymodel);
>         }
>
>         return View(model);
>      }
>
>    public IActionResult Payment(PaymentModel model)
>     {
>         return View();
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> }

Payment.cshtml:

> var stripe = Stripe('pk_test_wzPMgm92Bipuq1SJohxK3lOK00igaEN4Hs');
>       stripe.redirectToCheckout({
>           sessionId: '@Model.ChargeID',
>       }).then(function (result) {
>           result.error.message = "Oops! Looks like something went wrong. Please try again later."
>       });
>
> RegistrationModel.cs:
>
> public class RegistrationModel
>       {
>           [Required]
>           public int ID{ get; set; }
>
> ```
>     [Surname]
>     public string Surname{ get; set; }
> }
> ```
>
> PaymentModel.cs:
>
> public class PaymentModel
>       {
>           public string ChargeID { get; set; }
>       }

Comment: Can you add more of your code? Where does the form action submit to? What database actions are you taking? Which Checkout are you referring to with Stripe? https://stripe.com/docs/checkout? What have you already tried? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Many thks for response. I used the asp.net core RAZOR pages scaffolding option to create CRUD pages connecting to DB. All works fine, I only use Create page, which on clicking 'Create' writes to the DB fine. I have another asp.net core MVC project which has simple MVC with view page with Submit button which adds single payment record into a Stripe account using Stripe.Checkout(Add Line item), No DB connection, works fine. Really looking for best method approach to get the write record to DB and write to Stripe all in one project (either MVC or Razor) on one Submit button. Hope makes sense, thk

Comment: I have MS Access background (I know its not good) but its easy to put two events on one button, if that makes sense. Im not sure how to approach this being a newbie to web based coding. I can post all my code for both Razor and MVC which is'nt much if it helps?

Comment: I looked at stripe.com/docs/checkout and I can get the payment to work fine, what I would like to achieve is get that payment on the same button as my write to DB which is my 'Create' button generated by the scaffolding new item (CRUD) routine

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand what is happening or how you can hook into the submit event from the Razor page. Can you share more of your code?

Comment: Hi Yes, thank you, I will post all the code

Comment: Create.cshtml <form method="post">
           <div class="form-group">
             <input asp-for="Amtratable.Surname" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amtratable.Surname" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>

Comment: okay and what about your server code?

Comment: public class CreateModel : PageModel {
          private readonly StripeRazorJCG.Data.AMTRA_DB_LiveContext _context;
        public CreateModel(StripeRazorJCG.Data.AMTRA_DB_LiveContext context)
        { _context = context;}   public IActionResult OnGet()        {
        ViewData["IntAmtorgregistrationId"] = new SelectList(_context.TblSqpregistration, "IntRegsqpregistrationId", "IntRegsqpregistrationId"); return Page();} [BindProperty]

Comment: public Amtratable Amtratable { get; set; } public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()  {if (!ModelState.IsValid){
                return Page();  }   _context.Amtratable.Add(Amtratable);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToPage("./Index"); }}

Comment: MVC Stripe view - @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Email Address</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
    </div>
    
    
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </div>
}

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
    { public IActionResult Index()
        { RegistrationModel model = new RegistrationModel();
            return View(model);
        } [HttpPost]  public IActionResult Index(RegistrationModel model)  {
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
                List<SessionLineItemOptions> items = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>();
                if (model.FridayAdults > 0)
                { items.Add(new SessionLineItemOptions { Amount = 700,
                        Currency = "gbp",                  });
                }

Comment: var options = new SessionCreateOptions {
                    CustomerEmail = model.Email, PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                    { "card"
                    }, LineItems = items, };
                SessionService service = new SessionService();
                Session session = service.Create(options); PaymentModel paymodel = new PaymentModel { ChargeID = session.Id };
                return View("Payment", paymodel);
            }  return View(model);
        }  public IActionResult Payment(PaymentModel model) {
            return View(); }}

Comment: Model - public class RegistrationModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

    }

Comment: public class PaymentModel
    {
        public string ChargeID { get; set; }
    }
}

Comment: In essence how do i action the following event from a clickable button? StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = "sk_test_H2rZ53...";
var options = new SessionCreateOptions {PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions {SetupFutureUsage = "off_session",    },
    Customer = "cus_123", PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> {
        "card",},
    LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions> {new SessionLineItemOptions {
            Name = "... etc

Comment: Thanks ASPBeginner, can you add all of this code to your original question so that it's formatted nicely? It's almost impossible to read in the comments like this.

Comment: server: -  public class CreateModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly StripeRazorJCG.Data.AMTRA_DB_LiveContext _context;

        public CreateModel(StripeRazorJCG.Data.AMTRA_DB_LiveContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        public IActionResult OnGet()
        {
            ViewData["IntAmtorgregistrationId"] = new SelectList(_context.TblSqpregistration, "IntRegsqpregistrationId", "IntRegsqpregistrationId");
            return Page();
        }

Comment: [BindProperty]
        public Amtratable Amtratable { get; set; }

        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for
        // more details see https://aka.ms/RazorPagesCRUD.

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
                            

            _context.Amtratable.Add(Amtratable);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Create");

        }

    }


}

Comment: Can I place the Stripe Charge checkout in the 'on post async' code when asp writes the db record ie

Comment: public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
        {
                            

            _context.Amtratable.Add(Amtratable);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return RedirectToPage("./Create");

        }

Comment: ASPBeginner, can you edit your original question and put the code there rather than in the comments? If you put your code in the question you can use code formatting.